# python3 -m venv invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

I'm trying to run this specific line, but I am getting an error.
I am using the command prompt and I installed python to path when I check the install to path option on the windows python.exe

```
>>> python3 -m venv tutorial-env
   File "<stdin>", line 1
     python3 -m venv tutorial-env
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That command should be [run from your OS-level shell](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html), not from Python:

```
$ python3 -m venv tutorial-env
```

or on Windows:

```
C:\> python3 -m venv tutorial-env
```

Depending on how Python was installed you might need to use `python` or even `python2` instead of `python3`.