Unable to create virtual environment using virtualenv on Spyder IDE
I'm using Spyder IDE 5.51, Python 3.12.4 64-bit. I have installed virtualenv 20.28.0 on my Windows computer. I tried to create a virtual environment using the following code on Sypder Console by typing:
python3 -m venv myenvpath

I got the following error message:
Cell In[22], line 1
python3 -m venv myenvpath
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Could someone please explain to me why I got the above invalid syntax error? Thank you

Here you have the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42429564/6279885. You are trying to run that command from Python's interactive shell, not from your OS one.
